# Help understanding rewrite log (want to internally rewrite a page when requested from specific HTTP_HOST)

Tags: apache, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Drupal site, *site.com*, and our client has a campaign that they're promoting for which they've bought a new domain name, *campaign.com*. I'd like it so that a request for *campaign.com* internally rewrites to a particular page of the Drupal site. Note Drupal uses an .htaccess file in the document root.

The normal Drupal rewrite is

```
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I added the following *before* the normal rewrite.

```
# Custom URLS (eg. microsites) go here
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =campaign.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
RewriteRule ^ index.php?q=node/22 [L]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, it just shows the homepage. Turning on the rewrite log I get this.

```
1. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/ -> 
2. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] applying pattern '^' to uri ''
3. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (2) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] rewrite '' -> 'index.php?q=node/22'
4. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (3) split uri=index.php?q=node/22 -> uri=index.php, args=q=node/22
5. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> D:/wamp/www/index.php
6. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (2) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] strip document_root prefix: D:/wamp/www/index.php -> /index.php
7. [rid#2da8ea8/initial] (1) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
8. [rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/index.php -> index.php
9. [rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
10.[rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/index.php -> index.php
11.[rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
12.[rid#2da7770/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir D:/wamp/www/] pass through D:/wamp/www/index.php
```

I'm not used to mod_rewrite, so I might be missing something, but comparing the logs from a call to http://site.com/node/3 and from http://campaign.com/ I can't see any meaningful difference. Specifically `uri` and `args` on line 4 seem correct, the `internal redirect` on line 7 seems right, and the `pass through` on line 12 seems right (because the file index.php exists). But for some reason it seems the query string's been discarded/ignored around the time of the internal redirect. I'm completely stumped.

Also, if anyone could provide a reference on understanding the rewrite log, that might help. It'd be great if there's a way to track the query string through the internal redirect.

FWIW I'm using WampServer 2.1 with Apache 2.2.17.

Comment: try removing the = in rewritecond

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. The = I believe indicates a test for lexicographical equality. I don't _think_ that the problem's with either of the `RewriteCond` directives because the rewrite log seems to indicate that the rule executes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question, it's something that I need to do too.  I don't know the way to do this by means of the .htaccess, and hope that someone here can answer that.

But I do the same thing by using Drupal's menu system with this code in a custom module:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
    $items['domain_redirect'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'domain_redirect',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
   );
  return $items;
}



function domain_redirect() {

switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
{
  case "campaign.com":
    $goto = "node/22";
  break;
  default:
    $goto = "/";
}

    drupal_goto($goto);
}
```

Then set the frontpage to domain_redirect.

Comment: Very nice thanks, never occurred to me to do it in Drupal. I thought you'd need to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` though? Also I wonder if a better place to put it would be `custom_url_rewrite_inbound()`. Would be good as you say to see an .htaccess solution as well. A problem I was expecting to encounter if I got the .htaccess working was Drupal creating links based on the new domain name (eg. _campaign.com_). Have you experienced that?

Comment: Btw, how do you get the path `domain_redirect` to be executed? .htaccess internal rewrite? (Or have I missed something entirely?!)

Comment: I don't know which is better for this, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] or $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].  Either works for my purposes. Yes the links for the new domain are all relative to that domain sitewide, which has to be taken into account. Also, one unexpected side-effect is the need to empty cache when logged in from new domain after significant content changes. I execute domain_redirect by setting the homepage to domain_redirect in "site information" in settings.  Not a perfect solution, and am learning as I go with this thing. Investigating custom_url_rewrite_inbound() now, thanks!